# Search within a category in worpdress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm trying to search within a single category on wordpress using the code below

`

```
    $args = new WP_Query( 'cat=199' );
    if( $args->have_posts() ){

    while ( $args->have_posts() ){ $args->the_post();
        get_template_part('content', 'what-we-eat');

    } ?>

    <?php   

    }
    else{
        _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
    }
```

`

however, the results shows all of the posts within that category even though the search term updates with the search term used.

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

**EDIT**

I've noticed then when I remove my custom query it works, but pulls in posts from all of the categories on my blog which is what I don't want. So it's a question of excluding all other categories

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 199 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this only shows the first result in the category. It ignores the search term completely

Answer (score 0):

You want standard WP search to work in only one category?
Try to add this code to the functions.php of your theme:

```
function search_rules($query) {
  if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('cat','199');
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_rules');
```

Comment: i have two search bars, one that searches the main site and one that searches another area of the site